# The report viewer is not accepted enableDatabaseLogonPrompt which is false

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, ado.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I created a report. I have used ado.net connection. I created dataset from the add new project. I configured dataset and I called this dataset from the report. at the time is OK. And I wrote this in code-behind.

```
Dim Adp As New ClientDsTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter
Dim Rpt As New Client

Rpt.Load(Server.MapPath(Client_FILE))
Rpt.SetDataSource(CType(Adp.GetData(), DataTable))

Client.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = False
Client.ReportSource = Rpt

Dim ConnectionInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "MyServer"
ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyDB"
ConnectionInfo.UserID = "MyUser"
ConnectionInfo.Password = "MyPassword"
ConnectionInfo.Type = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfoType.SQL
ConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = True

For Each TableLogOnInfoVar As TableLogOnInfo In ClientReportViewer.LogOnInfo
    TableLogOnInfoVar.ConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfo
Next
```

And I set EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = "false" in report viewer. Now, The report first page is OK. When I go to next page and clicks anything on the reportviewr, I got a error. The error is this.

```
Logon failed. Details: crdb_adoplus : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error in File
```

How can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

Is all the data that your report needs present in your dataset?

```
CType(Adp.GetData(), DataTable)
```

If so, then you don't need to set the connection info, because you have already pushed all the data to the report, and it shouldn't be trying to request more data from the server.

Edit:

Does the

```
Adp.GetData()
```

get all of the data for the report?  If so, then remove all of the code below and try it again:

```
Client.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = False

Dim ConnectionInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "MyServer"
ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyDB"
ConnectionInfo.UserID = "MyUser"
ConnectionInfo.Password = "MyPassword"
ConnectionInfo.Type = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfoType.SQL
ConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = True

For Each TableLogOnInfoVar As TableLogOnInfo In ClientReportViewer.LogOnInfo
    TableLogOnInfoVar.ConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfo
Next
```

Comment: But I cannot go to next page or other button of report viewer.